# How to extract a list data inside quote after unnest command

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

First of all I have to change my question (I'm unable to post new question) so I'm hoping this new one will get some (+) votes to keep my capability in posting in SO. Apologize to SO community but I'm here trying to learn just like everybody else.
I have an activity dataset that I'm using to create histogram for each activities. One column is "activity" and I need to extract the elements from the activity column, however it has 2 variables - `type` and `confidence`.

```
>tail(df)
timestampMs                                                         activity
9104 1415996184265      IN_VEHICLE, UNKNOWN, ON_BICYCLE, STILL, 73, 23, 2, 2
9105 1415996140727                UNKNOWN, IN_VEHICLE, ON_BICYCLE, 71, 27, 2
9106 1415996055604                                              TILTING, 100
9107 1415995996249 UNKNOWN, ON_BICYCLE, ON_FOOT, UNKNOWN, IN_VEHICLE, STILL, 46, 25, 17, 17, 8, 4
9108 1415995854775                                              TILTING, 100
9109 1415995976124                                              TILTING, 100
```

I used `lapply` and it would list and arrange the values shown below.

```
> df$activity <- lapply(df$activity, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))
> tail(df$activity)
[[1]]
                    1       2          3     4
type       IN_VEHICLE UNKNOWN ON_BICYCLE STILL
confidence         73      23          2     2
[[2]]
                 1          2          3
type       UNKNOWN IN_VEHICLE ON_BICYCLE
confidence      71         27          2

[[3]]
                 1
type       TILTING
confidence     100

[[4]]
                 1          2       3       4          5     6
type       UNKNOWN ON_BICYCLE ON_FOOT UNKNOWN IN_VEHICLE STILL
confidence      46         25      17      17          8     4

[[5]]
                 1
type       TILTING
confidence     100
```

Then I used the `unnest` function;

```
df2 <- df %>%
   transform(activity = str_split(activity, ",")) %>%
   unnest(activity)
```

It list all elements in the `lapply` including the confidence variables (this is for the 4th element).

```
 timestampMs                        activity
 1415995996249       list(type = c("UNKNOWN"
 1415995996249                  "ON_BICYCLE"
 1415995996249                     "ON_FOOT"
 1415995996249                     "UNKNOWN"
 1415995996249                  "IN_VEHICLE"
 1415995996249                     "STILL")
 1415995996249            confidence = c(46
 1415995996249                           25
 1415995996249                           17
 1415995996249                           17
 1415995996249                            8
 1415995996249                          4))
```

What I want is for each timestamp it will list the types (I'm using same timestamp). What is the best way to extract values inside double quotes and if there are no quotes like the last 6 lines I can just make it N/A or blank which can be easily filtered later on:

```
timestampMs            activity    
1415995996249         "UNKNOWN"
1415995996249      "ON_BICYCLE"
1415995996249         "ON_FOOT"
1415995996249         "UNKNOWN"
1415995996249      "IN_VEHICLE"
1415995996249           "STILL"
```

Comment: Try creating an issue at https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim/issues for the missing variable definition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will do that as well.

Comment: Got a response that they have switched to revgeo package. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand I can't post more questions and although this new updated question didn't get any feedback, but as a professional that's ok. SO is not the only site I can ask questions. I do hope the status will change in the future because I know I can contribute. In any case I still would like to share some of the details. Just found a way to `unnest` the matrix myself and was able to derive the desired output. Used `unnest(df$activity)` then applied `melt` function in the output to get this table:
From this table in wide format:

```
> tail(df2) *#result of unnest*

       timestampMs       1          2       3       4          5     6    7
18213 1415995996249 UNKNOWN ON_BICYCLE ON_FOOT UNKNOWN IN_VEHICLE STILL <NA>
18214 1415995996249      46         25      17      17          8     4 <NA>
18215 1415995854775 TILTING       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>       <NA>  <NA> <NA>
18216 1415995854775     100       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>       <NA>  <NA> <NA>
18217 1415995976124 TILTING       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>       <NA>  <NA> <NA>
18218 1415995976124     100       <NA>    <NA>    <NA>       <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

To this table and just ran some manipulations.

```
> tail(df3) *#result of melt*

          timestampMs   activity    value
 18213  1415995996249   1         UNKNOWN
 36431  1415995996249   2      ON_BICYCLE
 54649  1415995996249   3         ON_FOOT
 72867  1415995996249   4         UNKNOWN
 91085  1415995996249   5      IN_VEHICLE
109303  1415995996249   6           STILL
127521  1415995996249   7             NA
```